# how to get count of child inside the parent child

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, children

[database rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4oiq.png)

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PbVK.png)

I have a problem with writing data  in firebase database 
It must give an id for the data using method  postId()
Sometimes its give me a right id and another time wrong id or updata data in an id was created

the id must be like this for all user post

[user1]

postId1

postId2

postId3

postId4

postId5

.

.

postId100000

---

[user2]

postId1

postId2

postId3

postId4

postId5
.

.

postId100000

........................................................................

```
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {


            mDatabase.child("AdUsersINFO").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(POSTID).setValue(adver,
                    new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            if (databaseError == null) {


                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data is saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data isn,t saved , please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

            mAdUserDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdUsersINFO").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(POSTID);
            mAdUserDatabse.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    mAdUserDatabse.child("userid").setValue(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }
```

private void postId() {

```
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdUsersINFO");
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChild(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                // run some code

                mAdUserDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdUsersINFO");
                mAdUserDatabse.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.e(snap.getKey(), snap.getChildrenCount() + "");

                            if (snap.getChildrenCount() != 0) {

                                postId = "postId" + String.valueOf(snap.getChildrenCount() + 1);
                                SharedPreferencesUtils.setStringPreference(getActivity(), "postId", postId);

                            } else {
                                postId = "postId" + String.valueOf(1);
                                SharedPreferencesUtils.setStringPreference(getActivity(), "postId", postId);
                            }


                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            } else {
                postId = "postId" + String.valueOf(1);
                SharedPreferencesUtils.setStringPreference(getActivity(), "postId", postId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

please save my life

Comment: What do you want to have in your output? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running a loop and overwriting value of `postId` again and again, so the `postId` is equal to the count of last child. So you're always getting the `postId` count for last user.

so have a look again at the part

```
for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.e(snap.getKey(), snap.getChildrenCount() + "");

                        if (snap.getChildrenCount() != 0) {

                            postId = "postId" + String.valueOf(snap.getChildrenCount() + 1);
                            SharedPreferencesUtils.setStringPreference(getActivity(), "postId", postId);

                        } else {
                            postId = "postId" + String.valueOf(1);
                            SharedPreferencesUtils.setStringPreference(getActivity(), "postId", postId);
                        }


                    }
```

Consider using separate key for every user's `postId` or make a function to get key for one user something like this

```
public void getPostId(String userId) {
    final String postId = "post";
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdUsersINFO").child(userId);
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            long c = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            if(c==) postId = postId+"1";
            else postId = postId+ c+1;
        },

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: thax for help :)